# How to check if the URL in android browser contains a given string?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, mobile

I am trying to check if a string is part of the page URL in various android browsers using the following code. It doesn't work in any android device. When I check in iOS devices or in desktop (windows OS) browsers it works fine.

Any ideas??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    if(window.location.href.indexOf("apieceofstring") > -1){
         alert("success");
    }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

> The **indexOf()** method returns the index within the calling String
>   object of the first occurrence of the specified value, starting the
>   search at fromIndex. Returns **-1** if the value is **not found**.

it mean your statement always true you need to do something like this

```
if (window.location.href.indexOf("apieceofstring") > -1) {
  alert("success");
}
```

Comment: My mistake.. I did not post the entire code. This is exactly what I am doing. I am editing it now.

Answer (score 0):

First of all if you want to program in android then write your code in java. Secondly use regex for finding out if a string contains another sub-string http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_regular_expressions.htm

Comment: Incorrect. if it is a [hybrid app](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_in_mobile_devices#Hybrid_Mobile_Apps), he does not need Java.